# JQuery UI draggable mouse up not recognised

Tags: jquery, draggable

I have a rather peculiar problem. I have implemented draggable, and it works properly when I use it on a div or paragraph, etc.

But I have the following situation, I have a table with 5 rows and one column. Inside the first cell, I have a div. Now I want to drag that div from there, and place it in the last row. But if it is placed anywhere else, it should revert.

The problem that I am facing is - when I begin dragging, the div gets stuck under the mouse pointer even after the mouse button is released. Some times, it works properly, and reverts... and other times, it is just stuck under the pointer and moves around as I move it. Is this a jQuery bug?

Comment: Probably. Have you tried other versions of JQuery UI? They're fixing/introducing bugs all the time.

Comment: Assume I have two divs A and B. I have a div X inside A. I want to move it from A to B... How do I do this? This should work with the standard code, right?

Comment: Make a fiddle and link us: http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @AlienWebguy - Thanks for the suggestion. As I was making that fiddle, I decided to strip off some of the code which I felt would be unnecessary, and found it worked. Turns out there was a conflict with another plugin - Right Click context menu plugin that I was using... On removing that, it works properly...

Comment: I posted an official answer - glad you found the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Remove the plugin which is causing the conflict.